# Rails scope testing for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an expenses table.  It has a column invoice_id.

I would like 2 scopes - one for billed expenses and one for not billed.
I thought I could just test to see if invoice_id was nil.

```
scope :notbilled, where(:invoice_id == nil)
scope :billed, where(:invoice_id != nil)
```

But, that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the first one, you need to use hash syntax:

```
scope :notbilled, where(:invoice_id => nil)
```

The second requires you to use raw sql:

```
scope :billed, where('invoice_id is not null')
```

You can also jump down into arel for the second one to avoid writing raw sql, but that's an advanced topic and would end up less readable than the raw sql.

Using direct equality won't work, because those expressions are evaluated immediately, and are turned into their boolean equivalents because no variables are involved, so they would be interpreted as

```
scope :notbilled, where(false)
scope :billed, where(true)
```

Comment: I changed it to your suggestion.  But, using `<% @expenses.billed.each do |expense| %>` - I get undefined method `notbilled' for #<Array:0x007fa461d18e88>

Comment: Why would calling `billed` produce an error about `notbilled`? Scopes are not intended for arrays - they are for relations. `@expenses` is the resultset of a query, so the time to call a scope on it has already passed.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the second index.  It is from this statement. <% @expenses.notbilled.each do |expense| %>

Comment: Can you show how `@expenses` is being assigned? That's where the root is this new issue is.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  But, I'm new to RoR.  What does @expenses being assigned mean?  The code is from the index page.

Comment: Where is `@expenses` coming from?

Comment: The line of code is from expenses/index.html.erb.  It originally was <% @expenses.each do |expense| %>.  And that works fine, to list all of the expenses.

Comment: `@expenses` is being set in a controller somewhere. That's what I need to see.

Comment: class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /expenses
  # GET /expenses.json
  def index
    @expenses = Expense.all

Comment: That's the problem. `Expense.all` pulls all the expenses from the database, forgoing any chance to use a scope on them. To fix it and make your views work like you want, you can either change that line to `@expenses = Expense.scoped`, or set separate variables, like `@billed = Expense.billed` and `@unbilled = Expense.notbilled`

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer as of Rails 4:**

```
scope :notbilled, where(invoice_id: nil)
scope :billed, where.not(invoice_id: nil)
```

This is a new feature added in ActiveRecord 4.

Docs: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html  (search for "NOT Conditions", currently section 2.4)